# Why would fiber optic enabled with mainline power but disabled with electric generator?

Tags: power, internet-connection, fiber, iptv

I live in Puerto Rico and recently we have had an power loss for a week because of Hurricane Fiona

I have fiber optic with my internet provider and IPTV also.  The internet didn't work when we were using the electric generator after being off for 12 hours for rest.

We had electricity with the generator for a long week, but without internet, without a logical explanation. But, when the power was re-established, the internet was enabled like magic.

Every neighbor in my community with the same service provider had no problem with the internet although off for 12 hours also. So, the problem is it's just in my house.

Any idea of what's causing this weird situation?

Comment: Voltage and / or phase out of tolerance for the Fiber power supply.

Comment: could have been a fiber repeater right outside your house that didn't have power as well

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments.  @Giacomo1968, my neighbors has their individual generator.  Every family has theirs.

Comment: Were your router and ISP's modem powered up during the outage? Could you access the router and/or modem from your computer (doesn't require internet)?

Comment: @giacomo1968 my power generator is different, everyone has a different one, but mine is a 30K generator.  Runs air conditioners, electric equipment, pool, water heater, etc., everything ran right with the generator.

Comment: @harrymc: modem, router, switch, music, and other stuff are connected via ethernet cables in my laundry room.  They had all the lights on with mainline power and with the generator.  I have access to them and I did many things before writing here including connecting my computer directly to the modem.  The computer had no connection to the internet with the power generator.

Comment: I asked 4 people related to this stuff and their answers are: it's weird!! It's just unbelievable, and the service provider technicians aren't very helpful because everyone in my neighborhood has service and I am the only one with the problem.

Comment: If router & modem were reachable and seemed to work, you might need to test the power output of your generator regarding quality and if it supplies enough power to run everything.

Comment: @harrymc thank you